# I get the error "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed." when trying to make an action

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

Not really sure why this is happening. I want to send a leaderboard with some data. I already made it work as part of my view/ but i wanted to implement it in an action. Yet when I do it, I get this error. This is my code in my view file

```
@action (methods="GET", detail=False, serializer_class=LeaderboardSerializer, permission_classes=[AllowAny])
    def Leaderboard(self, request):
        return Response({
            "results": str(request.results)
        },status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

[Not working :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqBRn.png)

Comment: did you write the api? if not I would check to see if you need to authenticate yourself somehow